# NumPy has no attribute array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create an array and display it's contents and append a new item however I am encountering an error:

```
C:\Users\Dylan Galea\Desktop\Modelling and CS>python numpy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Dylan Galea\Desktop\Modelling and CS\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
x=np.append([x,[5],0])
print(x)
```

Comment: Rename your script from `numpy.py` to something else

Comment: still the same error is being outputted

Comment: You don't have a file called `numpy.py` or a folder called `numpy` in the directory in which you're calling the script?

Comment: Ok it worked now the problem was that the other file was not deleted while chanign the file name

Answer (score 4):

You should not name your file `numpy`.

When you are doing `import numpy as np` your script imports itself rather than the "real" `numpy` module.